# How to fix Gqueue memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, glib

I've been testing this small code trying to learn how to use glib, and i came up with this memory leaks when using Gqueue . this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main (){
    GQueue *test = NULL;
    test = g_queue_new();
    g_queue_push_tail(test,"hola mundo");
    printf("%s \n",(char *)g_queue_peek_head(test));
    g_queue_free(test);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is wath valgrind shows

```
==36160== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==36160== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==36160== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==36160== Command: ./testgqueue
==36160== 
hola mundo 
==36160== 
==36160== HEAP SUMMARY:
==36160==     in use at exit: 18,636 bytes in 7 blocks
==36160==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 2 frees, 19,684 bytes allocated
==36160== 
==36160== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 7
==36160==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==36160==    by 0x48B7E98: g_malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6)
==36160==    by 0x48D0485: g_slice_alloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6)
==36160==    by 0x48D0AAD: g_slice_alloc0 (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6)
==36160==    by 0x1091E1: main (in /home/adolfo/Documents/cosas/testGlib/testgqueue)
==36160== 
==36160== LEAK SUMMARY:
==36160==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==36160==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==36160==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==36160==    still reachable: 18,612 bytes in 6 blocks
==36160==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==36160== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==36160== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==36160== 
==36160== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`g_queue_clear()` frees the memory of the queue elements, but not the queue itself. You need

```
g_queue_free(test);
```

after that.

Comment: Usign ```g_queue_free(test) or g_queue_free_full(test,free)``` i get the same memory leaks

Comment: Don't use `q_queue_free_full()` if the values weren't allocated with `malloc()`

Comment: I'know, i was just trying because ```g_queue_free(test)``` wasn't giving me results

Comment: All I can think of is that GQueue has some overhead that it doesn't free. I don't see a problem with your code.